# PHP : Class 'PDO' not found, Крон , Консоль

Tags: mysql, консоль, pdo, cron

Так и не нашел на просторах сети решения проблемы : класс PDO не находится при запуске скрипта из консоли или Крона.
В php.ini все прописано. При доступе к скрипту через сеть проблем нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `use PDO;` может поможет

Answer (score 0):

Решение было простым : запуск скрипта от web юзера, а не через root